# How to receive 5-digit data from Arduino using Pyserial?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm trying to receive data (arrays) from Arduino into my Python script, everything seems to be working fine until I try receiving a 5 or more digit number. Some searching suggests this probably has to do with Pyserial reading only a certain number of bytes at a time, but I am unable to understand what I need to change to be able to read my arrays. Please take a look at my codes:
Arduino code:

```
int data[] = {1245,2211,33498,4212,5235};
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  Serial.println(data[i]);
}

  //Commented this out because it'd give me garbage value in python
  //delay(1000);
}
```

Python Code:

```
import serial
ser1 = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600) 
#receive some data
for i in range(5):
   arduinoData = ser1.readline().decode('ascii')
   print(arduinoData)
```

Upon running this code I get:

1245

2211

-32038 (Why was this value converted into a negative number?)

4212

5235

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an overflow error on the Arduino side.

A signed integer (`int`) can take values from `-32768` to `32767` (as it is two bytes, each `8` bit making a `16` byte number so ranging from `-2^15` to `2^15-1`). Since `33498` is greater than that upper limit, it wraps around to a negative.

To redeem this, change your array of ints to a data type which supports larger positive intergers than `32767` - such as `uint_16`.

---

If you are interested, we can understand exactly why the negative number was `-32038`.

This is because all signed integers are represented using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two's_complement).

And in that system, `1000001011011010` (`33498`) is `-32038`.

To do that conversion, we negate it (to get it's positive representation( by inverting all its bits and add `1`:

```
1000001011011010 --> 0111110100100101 --> 0111110100100110 == 32038
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your 2's complements explanation was very insightful. Solved my problem by just changing int to double.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment

```
int data[] = {1245,2211,33498,4212,5235};
```

overflows for numbers outside the positive range of `int`, so the `data` array already contains the negative numbers.

Fix your c code

```
unsigned int data[] = {1245,2211,33498,4212,5235};
```

to send the data as intended .

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved it by changing int to double.